# How can I set Jenkins to display "Build failure" on failure of test cases?

Tags: maven, jenkins

On failure of test cases, it says that `[ERROR] There are test failures.` but also displays `FINISHED:Build Success` at the end, with Blue color in build history.
On failure and success it also sends mails using a dependency in my `POM.xml` which is

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>send a mail</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>send-mail</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                            <from>my email address</from>
                            <subject>Test Results</subject>
                            <failonerror>true</failonerror>
                            <mailhost></mailhost>
                            <receivers>

                                <receiver>recipientsemail</receiver>


                            </receivers>
                            <htmlMessageFile>
            /workspace/target/surefire-reports/emailable-report.html
                            </htmlMessageFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

This plugin is inside `<build>` tag.
**I want to send email of success and failure both, but it should also fail in Jenkins also.** I think something I need to change in Jenkins because I have already specified `<failonerror>true</failonerror>` in pom.xml.Please let me know what am I missing.
I am using Jenkins 1.466.2 (Debian/Ubuntu distribution).

Answer (score 1):

The [jenkins performance plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) allows you to create a test report and also define thresholds for an unstable or failed build.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **[Text-finder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin)** post-action plugin, to search console log for whatever RegEx that suits you, and downgrade the build to `FAILED` with that. As for sending emails, use Jenkin's **[Email Ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)** plugin. It has tons of options for different triggers, including test failures `UNSTABLE`